# Why does custom server work for pages/ but not app/?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have two nextjs apps, one with `pages/` and one with `app/`. However when I use the custom js server, only the `pages` one works. I am using the Custom JS Server described in the documentation

Edit:
The returned page is blank. Only

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

is returned.

.htaccess

```
PassengerAppRoot "/home/user/frontend"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerNodejs "/home/user/nodevenv/frontend/16/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile server.js
```

Comment: Can you give more information, how do you expect us to give you a solution with just a "it does not work"? Please add related error messages, server configuration, logs, etc..

Comment: There is no error message and the log is blank. Server is cpanel

Comment: And the app/ directory's contents looks correct to you? Running a local copy of that works? No browser console errors as well?

Comment: Running locally works. I can view the app content. But on cpanel only pages content works

Comment: If you add a text file to the app directory, are you able to see it in the browser? Is there an htaccess file or some configuration you haven't shared before? I think all we could say as well is "it should work" but you'll have to find any information that could be different between the directories. What happens if you swap or rename the directories? If renaming doesn't affect it, it is probably not the server configuration, but something in the app.

Comment: I have index.html which works, but all routes served by nextjs are not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255207/discussion-between-jjkivai-and-peter-krebs).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I am not sure why but changing next from `^13.4.19` to `13.4.10` solved the problem.